# Visual Studio 2012 Does Not Stop Scanning/Searching

Tags: search, visual-studio-2012, background

I use Visual Studio 2012 everyday for development.  For the past week, what seems to look like a search animation is constantly playing in the status bar.  What is this and how do I make it go away?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I wish someone could enlighten us on this, it is so distracting! :(